# True strike and critical confirmation

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, critical-hit

So last night, our party's wizard casted on himself true strike, so his next round's scorching ray would be a direct hit. He rolled on his round and rolled a natural 20. So It was a threat. My question is if the true strike counts towards beating critical confirmation ac. (Would his roll still be +20)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, because confirmation has the same modifiers as attack (all pluses and minuses).

As written in [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#criticalHits):

> ...you immediately make a critical roll—another attack roll with all the same modifiers as the attack roll you just made.

Comment: quick, clear and documented. Excellent, thanks, +1